# How to shuffle record in particular order???

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a website where i have two types of offer, Hot offer and Best Offer. I have 5 hot offer and 5 best offer. First 1 hot offer will come, then 1 best offer will come and so on. Now after 1 refresh the the 1st hot offer should replace 2nd hot offer, 2nd sholud replace 3rd hot offer, 3rd should replace 4th one, 4th should replace 5th hot offer and 5th hot offer should replace 1st hot offer. This should be same for best offer also.

It is like

**1st hot offer**

**1st Best Offer**

**2nd Hot Offer**

**2nd Best Offer**

........

........

........

........

**5th Hot Offer**

**5th Best offer**

After Refresh It should Be....

**5th Hot Offer**

**5th Best Offer**

**1st Hot Offer**

**1st Best Offer**

.......

........

........

.......

**4th Hot Offer**

**4th Best Offer**

Please help me. I am getting too much trouble in doing it.

Comment: You need to say how are the offers stored? Are they stored in an array ready to shuffle?

Answer (score 0):

This is the function you are looking for :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

You can define your ordering criteria to order your array with `usort`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know clearly your context, I just assume that:

1. You already have 2 arrays storing the hot offers and the best offers.
2. These 2 arrays have already been sorted in terms of "hot" and "best".

So,

```
// Normally, print hot offers and best offers 1 by 1,
// starting from the first offers.
for ($i = 0; $i < count($i); $i++) {
    echo $hotOffer[$i] . "<br />";
    echo $bestOffer[$i] . "<br />";
}

// In the case of shuffling, print the last offers first,
// then start printing from the second offers to the second last offers.
$lastRecord = count($i)-1;
echo $hotOffer[$lastRecord] . "<br />";
echo $bestOffer[$lastRecord] . "<br />";
for ($i = 1; $i < $lastRecord; $i++) {
    echo $hotOffer[$i] . "<br />";
    echo $bestOffer[$i] . "<br />";
}
```